# PHP/JS REGEX: In a string, how to replace 2 single quotes that are enclosed by angle brackets?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Example:

Change

`<a href='site.com'>Click Here</a>`

into

`<a href="site.com">Click Here</a>`

Comment: Step 1: choose an appropriate language. Step 2: post what you have tried. Step 3: post the problem(s) you encountered

Comment: Show what you have tried, then we can help you improve your regex. You want to learn from it eventually don't you?

Comment: `<a href='site.com'>` is valid anyways, why would you want to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript:**

```js
str.replace(/<(.*?)'(.+?)'(.*?)>/g,'<$1"$2"$3>');
```

**php:**

```php
preg_replace("/<(.*?)'(.+?)'(.*?)>/g",'<$1"$2"$3>',$str);
```

If you need to catch more than one group inside enclosed brackets then regex is kind of tricky, use this instead:

```js
var bracket = 0;
str = str.split("").map(function(c) {
  if (c === "<") bracket++;
  if (c === ">") bracket--;      
  if (c === "'" && bracket >= 1) {
    return '"';
  } else {
    return c;
  }
}).join("");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can accept the last answer, as I should also handle other html attributes of the anchor. I'm not that good in JQM, i dunno why it cannot handle `href='https://site.com' compared to href="https://site.com"`